# Heading to WC2014 Qualifier @ Wembley

Tags: budget, events, england, sports-events, football

I'm a long time Football fan living in the states.  I'm finally going to Europe and will be attending the England vs Moldova match.  One of my friends told me that football fans don't wear "kits/jerseys/shirts" to matches.  Is this true?

Also, where's a good place (£££ friendly) to pickup a authentic WC2014 "jersey"?

Comment: Just a note that official *World Cup* merchandise won't be available until around the time of the competition itself; and while you can buy an official England replica kit at a match at any time, there's [no guarantee that that will be the same kit as England end up using in Brazil in 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England_national_football_team#Historic_kits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your friend told you it's pretty inaccurate and the opposite is actually true: many people at the stadium DO wear jersey / shirt of their favorite team.

Authentic jerseys are sold pretty much everywhere at the same price, which is usually quite high. You can find "accurate enough" jerseys for lower prices, tho. Usually outside the stadium there are a bunch of sellers but prices are somewhat higher than those you can find in local markets during a non-match day.